# Unable to run ios app on device with new developer account

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

We are using a new developer account under the name of our company. I created and app with the id  and set it as the bundle identifier. I also created a developer certificate and a provisioning profile. When i run my app i get the following message:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/A3C8B1A7-8D87-4AC2-8A7A-542FD16D02EB/<MyApp>
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/A3C8B1A7-8D87-4AC2-8A7A-542FD16D02EB/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib: mmap() errno=1 validating first page of '/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/A3C8B1A7-8D87-4AC2-8A7A-542FD16D02EB/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib'
```

I am able to run the app on a simulator and i did not have such issues with previous developer account (which was not under the company name).

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An update on this issue and my solution:

I tried pretty much everything, including reinstalling xcode, removing everything from keychain and creating new certifications/provisioning profiles.

At the end the only thing that worked it to reinstall OSX (without formatting the disk).

Answer (score 0):

May be you accidentally revoked your certificate. Then all your swift projects have this problem. Although I solved them by using

```
rm -rf "$(getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR)/org.llvm.clang/ModuleCache"
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode
```

Good luck see if it helps. P.S. these reset your xcode settings

Comment: It already there. It seems like a provisioning issue, but i can't figure out what exactly

Comment: Have you set Embedded Content Contains Swift Code to YES?

Comment: I tried all of the solutions mentioned. The problem still happens

Comment: Have you add your new  account in xcode preferences.?

Comment: Yes, i added the account

Comment: Have u find the solution if not then I am  updating my answer. May be it will help you